# Move Zero KB files to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in which I have different files of different size. Now I have to write a batch script that will first find out the files of zero kb file size and then move those files in another folder. i have tried below But its not working. Could Someone Please look into it.

```
For /r %%F in ('E:/ABC/*.*') do
if %%~zF==0
Move E:\ABC\%%F E:\ABC\DEL
```

Comment: It is failing because `Move` needs to be on the same line as the `if` statement or else be contained within parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example

(I have a different directory and files containing spaces in their names)

```
@Echo off
for %%I IN (*.*) DO if %%~zI==0 Move "D:\TEMP\%%I" D:\TEMP2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "E:\ABC\"
for /r %%F in (*) do if "%%~zF"=="0" move "%%~fF" "E:\ABC\DEL\%%~nxF"
popd
```